# How to get a key in route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to get a key "category" in route "/category/1/"? Instead of a key "category" there can be another key (e.g catalog).

App component:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/category/:id/' element={<Categories />} />
   <Route path='/catalog/:id/' element={<Categories />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no dedicated function in `react-router-dom` for that but you can alternatively solve that with `useLocation` and a little bit of javascript.

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const key = pathname?.split('/')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can optionally pass a props like category = {true} or pass nothing for catalog.
Like this :

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/category/:id/' element={<Categories category={true} />} />
   <Route path='/catalog/:id/' element={<Categories />} />
</Routes>
```

Then in your `Categories` Component check `props.category`.
If you need more routing other than category or catalog you can pass string to determine which route it is.